# SIgned vs Unsigned bigint in Postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am using postgresql in my java springboot app.

If we have an `id` column (`bigint` type) in a table, then doesn't it makes sense to make it of type `unsigned bigint` as it will give us more higher limit of numbers before reaching the upper limit?

Comment: `id` sounds as if that is used as a primary key. As the **only** job of a primary key is to be unique, nothing prevents you from using negative numbers for that as well. But even if you don't want to use negative numbers for ids, if you burn 10000 values per second 24/7 without pause, it will take 29247120 years until you run out of values

Comment: There is no `unsigned bigint` in PostgreSQL, so you have no choice.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres [does not support unsigned integers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). If you have a real need to prevent negative values to be inserted in your column, you can use a check constraint (or, maybe, a domain), but I don't think that's what you are asking here.

The `bigint` datatype can store values up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`: you are not likely to exhaust that range anyway.